# How to create an incremental load with Salesforce as source in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-lake

Is there any way we can fetch the max of last modified date from the last processed file and store it in a config table

Answer (score 2):

From [Supported data stores and formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats) you can see Salesforce, Salesforce service cloud and Marketing cloud are supported.

You have to perform the following steps:

- Prepare the data store to store the watermark value.
- Create a data factory.
- Create linked services.
- Create source, sink, and watermark datasets.
- Create a pipeline.
- Run the pipeline.

Follow [this](https://www.cloudfronts.com/create-linked-service-with-salesforce-in-azure-data-factory/) to setup Linked Service with Salesforce in Azure Data Factory

[image]

When copying data from Salesforce, you can use either SOQL query or SQL query. Note that these two has different syntax and functionality support, do not mix it. You are suggested to use the SOQL query, which is natively supported by Salesforce.

Process for incremental loading, or delta loading, of data through a watermark:

In this case, you define a watermark in your source database. A watermark is a column that has the last updated time stamp or an incrementing key. The delta loading solution loads the changed data between an old watermark and a new watermark. The workflow for this approach is depicted in the following diagram:

[image]

ADF will scan all the files from the source store, apply the file filter by their LastModifiedDate, and only copy the new and updated file since last time to the destination store.

For capabilities, Prerequisites and Salesforce request limits refer [Copy data from and to Salesforce by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce)

Refer doc: [Delta copy from a database with a control table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-delta-copy-with-control-table) This article describes a template that's available to incrementally load new or updated rows from a database table to Azure by using an external control table that stores a high-watermark value.

This template requires that the schema of the source database contains a timestamp column or incrementing key to identify new or updated rows.

The template contains four activities:

- **Lookup**  retrieves the old high-watermark value, which is stored in an external control table.
- Another  **Lookup**  activity retrieves the current high-watermark value from the source database.
- **Copy**  copies only changes from the source database to the destination store. The query that identifies the changes in the source database is similar to 'SELECT * FROM Data_Source_Table WHERE TIMESTAMP_Column > “last high-watermark” and TIMESTAMP_Column <= “current high-watermark”'.
- **StoredProcedure**  writes the current high-watermark value to an external control table for delta copy next time.

Go to the **Delta copy from Database** template. Create a **New** connection to the source database that you want to data copy from.[image]

Create connections to the external control table and stored procedure that you created and   Select  **Use this template**.

Choose the available pipeline

For **Stored procedure name**, choose **[dbo].[update_watermark]**. Select **Import parameter**, and then select **Add dynamic content**.

[image]

click  **Add dynamic content** and Type in below query. This will get a  **maximum date**  in your watermark column that we can use for delta slice.

You can use this query to fetch the max of last modified date from the last processed file

```
select MAX(LastModifytime) as NewWatermarkvalue from data_source_table"
```

or

For files only you can use [Incrementally copy new and changed files based on LastModifiedDate by using the Copy Data tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-lastmodified-copy-data-tool)

Refer: Source:  [ADF Incremental loading with configuration stored in a table](http://sql.pawlikowski.pro/2018/07/01/en-azure-data-factory-v2-incremental-loading-with-configuration-stored-in-a-table/)